# AngularJs ng-repeat with track by not updated

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ng-repeat with track by clause (to optimize performance). I also have a custom directive which I use to process every tr:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in Products track by item.Id" 
    on-row-rendered="rowRendered">

app.directive('onRowRendered', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            debugger;
            $timeout(function() {
              scope.$emit(attr.onRepeatDone, element);
            });
          }
        }
    };
});
```

It works nice during the loading time (when Products are set first). But when model is changed (e. g. one of the items is updated) onRowRendered's link method is not called (I put debugger call there to check it out) while bindings are updated and html is correctly rerendered.

I expected AngularJs to call it at least for those items that were updated. Was I wrong in my expectations? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I've been digging into the code of the `ngRepeat` controller and I'm sorry to say, but this code won't work for the items that are being updated because the `ngRepeat` controller won't destroy the scope of the updated items, it will update the scope properties though ($index, $first, $last, etc), but it won't destroy the scope unless the item needs to be removed.

Your code would only work if all the scopes of all the items of the repeat were being destroyed and recreated every time that you make a change to the collection, but that is not how the `ngRepeat` controller operates.

But you may want to try this instead:

```
    .directive('onRowRendered', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {                                
            scope.$watch('item', function(){                      
                $timeout(function() {scope.$emit(attr.onRowRendered, element);});
            }, true);                
          }
        }
    });
```

This should `$emit` every time that an item is added or changed.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y2084yg5/)

Comment: Don't you think it is a bug?

Comment: No, it's not, it works like that in order to keep good performance and it makes sense. What it doesn't make sense to me is that it doesn't give you an option to pass a call-back function when it finishes to re-render. BTW, I've made an update to the answer, maybe that will help you.

Comment: I just made another update to the code that I suggested.